# Given  = 〈1, −4〉   = −2 + 6 find w such that...

Tags: linear-algebra

Given  = 〈1, −4〉   = −2 + 6, I need to find a vector W such that $$-4u - 1v +w = 0$$
My intuition tells me to just put the vectors $u$ and $v$ in the equation and isolate for $w$, is this the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: Yep.  Right off the bat you know that $w=4u+v$, and you know what $u$ and $v$ are.

Comment: It's the correct way. Please make an answer yourself, accept it and close it.

Answer (score 3):

Isolate for w  $$ w = 4u + v$$ and substitute vectors into equation.